# Angular GET request param with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a variable in Angular 1.5.11 generated from a module in the following format:

```
[{"fName":"mike"},{"fName":"john"}]
```

I am having trouble generating an $http GET request to send an `fName` parameter with both values of "mike" and "john".

Basically I need angular $http to generate this for a Ruby on Rails 5 server:

http://localhost:3000/sales.json?fName[]=mike&fName[]=john

Here is my controller code so far:

```
var receivedParams = [{"fName":"mike"},{"fName":"john"}];

$http({method: 'GET', url: '/sales.json', params: receivedParams})
  .then(function successCallback(response) {
    //do stuff
  });
};
```

How do I change the `receivedParams` to be properly sent in the GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`receivedParams` variable need to look like to get the expected result:

```
var receivedParams = { 'fName[]': ['mike', 'john'] }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, this is what I got stuck on. I think this format returns only the data for 'john' not 'mike'  I think this is doing: http://localhost:3000/sales.json?fName=mike&fName=john The difference is fName instead of fName[]. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @HoosierCoder try `{ 'fName[]': ['mike', 'john'] }`

Comment: You would think that would work but returns no data.. I think it needs some sort of serializer

Comment: please look at https://plnkr.co/edit/ax2FjmPYNVriMKTSkTFO?p=preview when you hit fetch your get in the network section of the developer tools of your brower the url as follow `https://run.plnkr.co/MQSJTpbiUNlZckf1/test.json?fName%5B%5D=mike&fName%5B%5D=john`. In this url is [] encoded as %5B%5D. In this case this should work. Otherwise I will suggest you to check the serverside code.Maybe you also need to define fName at the serverside as fName[]? What language do you use for server side?

Comment: Hmm fName%5B%5D=‌​mike&fName%5B%5D=joh‌​n only returns data for john. I am using ruby on rails..

Comment: I hoped you would say .NET or php (these languages I use frequently). But with some investigation on internet I saw that CGI.parse(URI.parse("your_url").query) should result the same what you used for receivedParams.

Comment: What I descriped in my previous comment I think you could loop through the array, but what will happen when only only 1 value for fName is passed, I expect that you get a sting value instead of an array.

Comment: Blahhh I'm on a nosql database trying to run a nested query, there was an issue there. { 'fName[]': ['mike', 'john'] } works. Maybe you should change your answer to that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQLike paramSerializer

```
//var receivedParams = [{"fName":"mike"},{"fName":"john"}];
var receivedParams = { fName: ["mike", "john"] };

$http({method: 'GET',
       url: '/sales.json',
       params: receivedParams,
       paramSerializer: $httpParamSerializerJQLike 
})
  .then(function successCallback(response) {
    //do stuff
  });
};
```

For more information see

- [AngularJS $httpParamSerializerJQLike API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)
- [jQuery.param() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)